# sql bulk insert never completes for 10 million records when using df.bulkCopyToSqlDB on databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bulkinsert, azure-databricks

I am reading 1 GB of CSV file ( record count : 10 million, columns : 13 ) and trying to dump it into the SQL server. Below are the infra details :

- CSV file location : azure blob storage
- Code : Spark + Scala
- Cluster : Databricks 
  Size : 
  [image]
- Code Used to read the file and dump it :

  val df = spark.read.format(fileparser_config("fileFormat").as[String]).option("header", fileparser_config("IsFirstRowHeader").toString).load(fileparser_config("FileName").as[String]).withColumn("_ID", monotonically_increasing_id)

  val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
          "url" -> connConfig("dataSource").as[String],
          "databaseName" -> connConfig("dbName").as[String],
          "user" -> connConfig("userName").as[String],
          "password" -> connConfig("password").as[String],
          "dbTable" -> tableName,
          "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "500000",
          "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
          "bulkCopyTimeout" -> "600"))

  println(s" ${LocalDateTime.now()} ************ sql bulk insert start ************")

  df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)

  println(s" ${LocalDateTime.now()} ************ sql bulk insert end ************")
- Problem :

**the cluster goes into a limbo and my job never completes. One time when it ran long enough it threw an error** :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 13 in stage 38.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 13.3 in stage 38.0 (TID 1532, 10.0.6.6, executor 4): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:227)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:796)\n\tat com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServ
```

- Cluster Event logs :

[image]

- Other observations :

  1. While the job runs for a very long time, the cluster is not completely unresponsive. I tried this by submitting more jobs in that same window. The job ran but took comparatively more time than usual( around 10x time)
  2. I tried increasing the worker nodes and the node type ( even chose 128 GB nodes ) but still the outcome was same.
  3. While the job was running, I tried checking the SQL table row count with nolock query. I ran this after 3-4 minutes while the job was running, it gave me around 2 million records in the table. But when I ran it again after 10 minutes, the query kept running forever and never returned any records.
  4. I have tried tweaking the bulkCopyBatchSize property but it hasnt helped much.
  5. I have tried to remove the sqlinsertion code and used an aggregation operation on the dataframe that i create from 1 GB file and the entire thing takes only 40-50 seconds, so the problem is only with sql driver/sql server.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

**Azure SQL Server** - Standard S7: 800 DTUs

**HDInsight** - 6 node (2 D13V2 Head and 4 D13V2 Worker)

**Data Size** - 100GB Parquet with 1.7 billion rows.

Initially I was using **"bulkCopyTimeout"** as 600 seconds and I observed the loading was restarting after the timeout passed. Then I changed the timeout to a very large value and it worked fine.

For performance improvement:

Create columnstore Index in the target table and use

**"bulkCopyBatchSize"** = 1048576 (Load whole batch into row-groups maximum capacity and compresses them directly into the column-store rather than loading into delta store and compressing later)

**"bulkCopyTableLock"** = "false" (in order to allow parallelism)